# Thumbnail url changed but is not reflected until resize ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Hello I have a image slider with some pictures. With the help of ajax I am changing the image url , the image is working fine. while in the case of thumbail I can see the changes reflected in console but it is not reflected on the webpage until i resize the page.

```
            console.log(url);
            $('.img1').attr("src",url+"/RUST_1.jpg");
            $('.img2').attr("src",url+"/RUST_2.jpg");
            $('.img1thumb').attr("data-thumb",url+"/RUST_1.jpg");
            $('.img2thumb').attr("data-thumb",url+"/RUST_2.jpg");

         <ul id="image-gallery"  class="gallery list-unstyled cS-hidden">              
         <li class="img1thumb" data-thumb="../images/<?php echo $item[0]->DESIGN; ?>/<?php echo $item[0]->COLOR_CODE;?>/RUST_1.jpg" >
         <img class="img1" class="card-img-top" class="img" src="../images/<?php echo $item[0]->DESIGN; ?>/<?php echo $item[0]->COLOR_CODE; ?>/RUST_1.jpg"  alt="Card image" style="width:100%" />
         </li>
         <li class="img2thumb" data-thumb="../images/<?php echo $item[0]->DESIGN; ?>/<?php echo $item[0]->COLOR_CODE; ?>/RUST_2.jpg" >
         <img class="img2" class="card-img-top" class="img" src="../images/<?php echo $item[0]->DESIGN; ?>/<?php echo $item[0]->COLOR_CODE; ?>/RUST_2.jpg"  alt="Card image" style="width:100%" />
         </li>
         </ul>
```

I found this in lightslider.js

```
var thumb = $children.eq(i * settings.slideMove).attr('data-thumb');
                    if (settings.gallery === true) {
                        pagers += '<li style="width:100%;' + property + ':' + thumbWidth + 'px;' + gutter + ':' + settings.thumbMargin + 'px"><a href="#"><img src="' + thumb + '" /></a></li>';
                    } else {
                        pagers += '<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>';
                    }
                    if (settings.mode === 'slide') {
                        if ((v) >= w - elSize - settings.slideMargin) {
                            i = i + 1;
                            var minPgr = 2;
                            if (settings.autoWidth) {
                                pagers += '<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>';
                                minPgr = 1;
                            }
                            if (i < minPgr) {
                                pagers = null;
                                $slide.parent().addClass('noPager');
                            } else {
                                $slide.parent().removeClass('noPager');
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please add all related code. `data-thumb` is no native `HTML` and is probably used with another `JS` lib.

Comment: I am working on someone elses scipt i don't see any css related to data-thumb. i am sure the site uses lightSlider for the slider but i don't see any reference to the data-thumb there too.
P.S.: it's shown as data-thumb in the element inspector too, is there anything i can do to help u futher in assisting

Comment: To find the solution you should first find out what code is responsible for actually rendering the thumbnails (reading `data-thumb` and doing stuff with it).
Then check if this library has something like an `update` method which causes it to re render the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste your time, but lightslider provides a public function to refresh the slider

Step 1: get an object of the light slider

```
slider = $(document).find('#image-gallery').lightSlider({});
```

Step 2: call refresh function after you change the images url

```
slider.refresh();
```

Source: https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider/blob/aa6c01e1e0fbf180eed67447471dfc24d29a3ae1/README.md